# Why is Angular's Tour of Heroes http error handler accepting arguments of type any?

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular's tour of hero tutorial the author writes an error handler for the http service (hero-service). I'm confused about why the author chose to make the error handler's error argument type any, when in other Angular documentations regarding http client, the error handler type is always specified as type httperrorresponse.

Here's the error handler in the tour of heroes tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#error-handling

```
  private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      console.error(error); // log to console instead

      // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
      this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

      // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }
```

And here is the error handler example provided in Angular's httpclient documentation https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details

```
private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
    console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
  } else {
    // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
    // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
    console.error(
      `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
      `body was: ${error.error}`);
  }
  // return an observable with a user-facing error message
  return throwError(
    'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
};
```

You can see that here the error argument type is specified as HttpErrorResponse. When should an error argument be typed as any, and when should it be more specific?

Also if I just had the handleError function take a untyped argument:

```
handleError(error){

}
```

Is that any different from doing

```
handleError(error: Any){

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors in RXJS are always of type `any`.  It would be entirely possible for any operator in the chain to throw any kind of error.  So it is a little unsafe to downcast to `HttpErrorResponse` but it is allowed.

If you only every had HttpClient connected to this error handler directly then it would be safe.  However, someone could add some kind of custom operator (maybe one that grabs from a cache of the response is not found) and that operator could throw some other error.  This would lead to a runtime exception.

The usual end result is that you end up hiding a bug.  A bug in an early operator leads to an error.  The error is then caught by this handler which hits another error because it isn’t an http response error.  Only the second error gets printed to the console.

So it’s probably better to take in `any` and make sure it’s the kind of exception you’re trying to handle if you want to be thorough.  But you can get away with accepting a more narrow type if you’re willing to take the risk.

I have no idea why the authors chose to do different things but the first handler is very generic and doesn’t do anything with the error object other than printing it so there is no advantage to down casting.  The second is probably just trying to be concise by down casting and not showing the extra checks.

Comment: Is there any need to specify the type as any, or will just writing the function signature like errorHandler(error) be enough?

Comment: If your error handler is defined as a stand-alone function like that then you should put in `any` (or even safer, `unknown`).  If you are defining a lambda or a catch block it can usually be inferred.